# Detect if hangup button is selected on bluetooth headset from voip app

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, voip

I need to detect when someone selects the hangup button on their bluetooth headset. My voip application only uses callkit on the first incoming call and I can't find a delegate for detecting hardware on the headset being selected.

Comment: This `CallKit` `CXCallObserverDelegate` method is called every time an `CXCallObserver` detects a change in the call state: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxcallobserverdelegate/1649009-callobserver. Then you can check the `hasEnded` property of the `CXCall` object in this delegate method.

Comment: is there a way to detect outside of callkit? Since I only use callkit for my first incoming call I would need to be able to detect if it is an outgoing all or my second incoming.

Comment: Detecting outside of CallKit is not recommended. The reason is because some headsets don't have a specific hang up button, so while you could detect the appropriate button press, it may not work as expected. You can detect if it's the second incoming call using the observer pattern I described above. Same goes for another outgoing call